# Apache Artemis and address routing

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm trying to understand how Artemis does its routing (I'm using Artemis 2.11.0). I would like to configure two different addresses `STATUS_LOG.V01` and `STATUS_LOG.V02`. From a JMS perspective one is a queue (V01) and one is a topic (V02). The topic should multicast its messages to the previously defined queue. I have the following in broker.xml:

```xml
<address name="STATUS_LOG.V01">
   <anycast>
      <queue name="STATUS_LOG.V01" />
   </anycast>
</address>
<address name="STATUS_LOG.V02">
   <multicast>
      <queue name="STATUS_LOG.V01" />
   </multicast>
</address>
```

When I send a message to the `STATUS_LOG.V01` address I see it in the `STATUS_LOG.V01` queue through the web UI as expected. When I publish a message to the `STATUS_LOG.V02` address I expect to see the message in the `STATUS_LOG.V01` queue, but I don't.

We have an existing queue which receives status messages (`STATUS_LOG.V01`) from endpoint adapters. Ultimately, we would like to add another destination (`STATUS_LOG.V02`) (a topic destination - PUBSUB behavior) to be used for future releases. However, we want the messages received on the new topic to be routed to the existing queue. Is this doable in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: Through the web UI

Comment: I'm trying to funnel one address to another (hence statically specifying the name).

Comment: Thanks Justin. That clarifies it. We have an existing queue which receives status messages (STATUS_LOG.V01) from endpoint adapters. We would like to add another destination  (STATUS_LOG.V02)  (a topic destination- PUBSUB behavior) to be used for future releases. However, we want the messages received on the new topic to be routed to the existing queue. Is this doable in Artemis?

Comment: I update your question with this important use-case description, and I also updated my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you Justin for the clarification and the solution. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the expected behavior since your configuration is not allowed. Queue names must be unique across the broker. You can't have the same queue bound to multiple addresses. You are trying to configure the queue `STATUS_LOG.V01` on both addresses `STATUS_LOG.V01` & `STATUS_LOG.V02`. When you start the broker you should see logging like this:

```
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address STATUS_LOG.V01 supporting [ANYCAST]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue STATUS_LOG.V01 on address STATUS_LOG.V01
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address STATUS_LOG.V02 supporting [MULTICAST]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying MULTICAST queue STATUS_LOG.V01 on address STATUS_LOG.V02
WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ229019: Queue STATUS_LOG.V01 already exists on address STATUS_LOG.V01
```

Notice the last `WARN` logged. This indicates that the queue `STATUS_LOG.V01` cannot be bound to address `STATUS_LOG.V02` since it is already bound on address `STATUS_LOG.V01`.

What you really need to do is create a [`divert`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/diverts.html) to take messages sent to your `STATUS_LOG.V02` address and forward them to your `STATUS_LOG.V01` address. Use this instead of your original configuration:

```xml
<address name="STATUS_LOG.V01">
   <anycast>
      <queue name="STATUS_LOG.V01" />
   </anycast>
</address>
<address name="STATUS_LOG.V02">
   <multicast/>
</address> 
<divert name="myDivert">
   <address>STATUS_LOG.V02</address>
   <forwarding-address>STATUS_LOG.V01</forwarding-address>
   <exclusive>true</exclusive>
</divert>
```

It's not clear to me whether or not you'll want to set `exclusive` to `true` for your use-case or not. If `exclusive` is `true` then none of the JMS topic subscribers on `STATUS_LOG.V02` will get the messages sent to `STATUS_LOG.V02`. All the messages sent to `STATUS_LOG.V02` will be diverted exclusively to `STATUS_LOG.V01`. If `exclusive` is `false` then the JMS topic subscribers on `STATUS_LOG.V02` will get messages sent to `STATUS_LOG.V02` and the messages will *also* be diverted to `STATUS_LOG.V01`. You can read more about diverts in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/diverts.html).